# CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND, OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR used as include directory

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, openssl, webrtc, libsourcey

I am trying to run **cmake** command

```
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF         
-DBUILD_MODULES=OFF -DBUILD_APPLICATIONS=OFF          
-DBUILD_SAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF          
-DWITH_WEBRTC=ON -DWITH_FFMPEG=ON          
-DBUILD_MODULE_base=ON -DBUILD_MODULE_crypto=ON          
-DBUILD_MODULE_http=ON -DBUILD_MODULE_json=ON          
-DBUILD_MODULE_av=ON -DBUILD_MODULE_net=ON          
-DBUILD_MODULE_socketio=ON -DBUILD_MODULE_symple=ON          - 
DBUILD_MODULE_util=ON -DBUILD_MODULE_uv=ON          
-DBUILD_MODULE_webrtc=ON -DWEBRTC_INCLUDE_DIRS=/tmp/webrtc-22215-ab42706-linux-x64/include/ 
-DWEBRTC_LIBRARIES=/tmp/webrtc-22215-ab42706-linux-x64/lib/ 
-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl
```

and ended with errors

```
 CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
 they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
 and tested correctly in the CMake files:
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/av/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/av
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/base/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/base
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/crypto/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/crypto
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/http/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/http
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/json/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/json
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/net/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/net
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/socketio/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used
 as include directory in directory
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/socketio
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/symple/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/symple
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/util/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/util
 /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/webrtc/OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR    used as
 include directory in directory /home/ubuntu/temp/libsourcey/src/webrtc
```

I have an OpenSSL include dir path manually then also getting the same error

```
-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl
```

How to resolve this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Your CMakeLists.txt defines OPENSSL as a required external lib. But it is not found.

```
find_library(OPENSSL ...)
```

Review the pathes cmake is looking for the library.

Review the pathes [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/find_library.html) is looking for the library.
To make this easier you can print out the variables used by `find_library`.

Print variables with `message(STATUS ${VARIABLE_NAME})`